# Asking a generic pet question

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently asked [What signs should I look for in my children to know they are ready for a pet](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/202/what-signs-should-i-look-for-in-my-children-to-know-they-are-ready-for-a-pet) with the hope that it would be a somewhat canonical question for a question I think we are going to see regularly.

However [pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pets) is rightfully blacklisted, so does anyone have any recommendations for tags for this question beyond what is there in order to adequately describe the question.

Comment: Care? That's a tricky one... it's about responsible pet ownership and that's kind of hard to tag.

Comment: @JohnCavan yeah it was, but why I asked here.  I have some thoughts I will put as answers.

Comment: Please all, upvote any that you think might be appropriate, or add your own.

Answer (score 9):

I think [children](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children) is sufficient, for now.  It is possible that we might get other questions in the future that are about the concept of being responsible enough to take care of a pet, that aren't directly relevant to children, but I'm having trouble imagining what those questions might be.  If we do wind up with some, we can revisit this, but in the meantime, I'm inclined to suggest just [children](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children) for now.

Answer (score -2):

What about [pet-responsibility](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pet-responsibility)?  It covers the grounds of being responsible for caring for a pet and does not seem to be too broad unlike my previous suggestion of [pet-care](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pet-care)

Comment: Still leaning towards the "meta tag" scope, but better than "pet-care" I think.

Answer (score -3):

I considered creating a [pet-care](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pet-care) are this would describe the content, but it is pushing into the meta tag area (or at least too broad of a tag) as it could almost be applied to most any question on the site.

Comment: I am not sure if I should down or upvote this answer. Whatever, I agree that pet-care would be too meta for the site.